# Should I re-plant my unbalanced indoor lucky bamboo plant, or will something else work?

Tags: indoors, plant-care, repair, lucky-bamboo

What is the best way to re-plant this plant, or help it to support itself?  The shoots are a bit too tall for the original stalk.

[image]

Comment: Not really a duplicate, but one option: [How to prune an overgrown Dracena](http://gardening.stackexchange.com/questions/8847/how-to-prune-an-overgrown-and-now-flowering-dracaena)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The best way to deal with this plant is to grow it under higher light conditions so it does not get so [etiolated](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Etiolation) or leggy.  This species is robust so you can cut the stems back where they come out from the main stem and root them in water.

You could probably cut the long stretched out stems into six inch chunks and root them in water even if they do not have leaves.  This plant is tough, it just needs light.